# keras custom loss - ignore zero labels

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, sequence

I am trying to train a sequence tagging model (LSTM), where the sequence labels are either `1` (first class) , `2` (second class) or `0` (don't care).

I tried to write my own loss function that ignores the zeros:

```
import keras.backend as K
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   """(sum([(t-p)**2 for t,p in zip(y_true, y_pred)])/n_nonzero)**0.5"""
   return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred*K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") - y_true), axis=-1) / K.sum(K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") ))
```

Which essentially calculates mean squared error only on non-zeros.

However, I get `loss=nan` when training the model.

What I am doing wrong ?

What is the standard way to ignore certain labels in the training process ?

Comment: `K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred*K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") - y_true), axis=-1) / K.sum(K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") ))` is supposed to be `K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred*K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") - y_pred), axis=-1) / K.sum(K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") ))`

Comment: You are subracting `y_true` by `y_true` instead of `y_pred`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is as it has to be:

```
K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred*K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") - y_pred), axis=-1) / K.sum(K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") ))
```

instead of:

```
K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred*K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") - y_true), axis=-1) / K.sum(K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") ))
```

as you are subtracting `y_true` by `y_true` instead of `y_pred`.

Comment: Can I ask: How does the operations work between y_pred and y_true>0, if the latter will have different dimensions after discarding the zero-values?? Is the multiplication essentially a mask ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by removing the argument of axis=-1:

`K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred*K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") - y_true), axis=-1) / K.sum(K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") ))`

Subtracting `y_true` by `y_pred` when `y_true` is greater than 0. In particular, when `y_true` is equal to zero the term `y_pred*K.cast(y_true>0, "float32") - y_true)` is also equal to zero because it subtracts 0 by 0, as in case of `y_true>0` the term `K.cast(y_true>0, "float32")` takes the value 1, otherwise it gets 0.